# How can I print the cyclical manner of an array in counter-clockwise order?

Tags: python, cycle

For example I have an array of:

```
array = {
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9
}
```

Is it possible if I can make it go counter-clockwise starting from 9 to 5, then the output should look like:

```
9 6 3 2 1 4 7 8 5
```

I want it in plain python with no imported modules, Thank you in advance!

This is what i tried but it just reverse

```
arr = {
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9
}

{print(i, end=' ') for i in list(arr)[::-1]}
```

Comment: iterate from bottom right to top, then top to left , left to bottom, bottom to right,  you can do anti clock wise

Comment: @sahasrara62 I don't know how to iterate it from side to side, can you give me an example? :)

Comment: Beware, your "array" is a Python set, which is an UNORDERED set, so you have no guarantee the initial order will be preserved; you'd better define it as a list; furthermore, I imagine you want the "spiraling" to work on arrays of any size; if that's the case and the array is always a square, that's ok, but if it can be a rectangle, rows should be clearly identified. All in all, can you give us several examples of arrays you'd like to treat ?

Comment: @Jethy11 https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix/ this is example, here movement is clock wise, you need to modify algo to make it anticlockwise

Answer (score -1):

Ok here's a recursive function that will spiral an array of any dimensions (square or rectangular); note that is empties the original array, so if you want to keep it, you'll have to first make a deepcopy of it:

```
array = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    [7,8,9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16,17,18],
    [19,20,21,22,23,24]
    ]

def spiral(array, sp=[] , direction = 0):
    # direction = 0 for up, 1 for left, 2 for down, 3 for right
    
    if array == []:
        return sp
    
    if direction == 0:
        for i in range(len(array)-1,-1,-1):
            sp.append(array[i][-1])
            del array[i][-1]
        return spiral(array, sp, 1)
    
    if direction == 1:
        sp += array[0][::-1]
        del array[0]
        return spiral(array, sp, 2)
    
    if direction == 2:
        for i in range(len(array)):
            sp.append(array[i][0])
            del array[i][0]
        return spiral(array, sp, 3)
    
    if direction == 3:
        sp += array[-1]
        del array[-1]
        return spiral(array, sp, 0)
    
    
print(spiral(array))
# [24, 18, 12, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 13, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 17, 11, 10, 9, 8, 14, 15, 16]
```